# Is there a way to set multiple passwords for a single account on macOS?

Tags: macos, user-account, authentication

I wonder if there is a way to set multiple passwords for a single user under macOS?

Comment: I would ask why? This sounds like an XY problem  and we might be able to provide a better solution .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, one password per account. You can authenticate as another user anytime the GUI asks for authorization, overriding the current user as the default choice, but there’s one correct password per account.